# How to import test cases from excel sheet to TFS (team foundation server)

Tags: testing, tfs-2015

I have tried using Test object tool which is used to get test cases from TFS to Excel sheet.

Now i would like to know how to import test cases to TFS(Team foundation server) again from excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way  to import your test case back to TFS is: Import your test cases from web portal by **copy and save**.

[image]

For more details take a look at [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d74b27f-8e84-425a-bc21-1c1111c371a4/import-test-cases-from-excel-to-tfs-2013?forum=tfsgeneral).

Comment: Thanks Patrick, i have done the steps as u said its working fine , but i have thousands of test cases which i need to upload.                                                                   Is there Tool that can help me upload in single run ?

Comment: For Exporting Test cases from TFS to Excel. There is a tool named as TestMigration tool. Which can Imports test cases perfectly. I am using it and it is a free tool.